# Error inserting row into sqLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So this is my first sqlite database and I'm running into an issue trying to insert rows into the database. All I want to do is insert integers into the sqlite database. Maybe theres a simpler method than what I'm Doing? Could I do it with the CheckedRoutes class?

Heres myDbHandler

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "checked_routes.db";
public static final String TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES = "checked_routes";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_checkedRoutes";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES +
            "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES);
    onCreate(db);
}


/////Add row to table
public void addCheckedRoute(CheckedRoutes checkedRoute){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, checkedRoute.get_checkedRoute());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES, null, values);
    db.close();
}

////Delete row from table
public void deleteCheckedRow(int checkedRoute){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES + "WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + checkedRoute + "\";" );
}
}
```

heres my CheckedRoutes

```
package com.example.zach.listview;


public class CheckedRoutes {

int _checkedRoute;

   public void set_checkedRoute(int _checkedRoute){
    this._checkedRoute = _checkedRoute;
   }

public int get_checkedRoute(){
    return _checkedRoute;
}
}
```

And heres how I'm trying to insert the rows

```
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
int listViewItemPosition;
listViewItemPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewItemPosition", 0);

 //add checked route position to database
 CheckedRoutes checkedRoute = new CheckedRoutes();
 checkedRoute.set_checkedRoute(listViewItemPosition);
 dbHandler.addCheckedRoute(checkedRoute);
```

and heres my error

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting _checkedRoutes=3
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: checked_routes._checkedRoutes (code 1555)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
                  at com.example.zach.listview.MyDBHandler.addCheckedRoute(MyDBHandler.java:39)
                  at com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails.onBackPressed(RouteDetails.java:109)
                  at com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails.onOptionsItemSelected(RouteDetails.java:88)
                  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:406)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:183)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

thank you for any help

Comment: Probably listViewItemPosition value is already exist in table as PRIMARY KEY value

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Is there a way to check and see if the value Already exists and if it does do not insert the value again?

Comment: Yes Use [insertWithOnConflict](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) with  CONFLICT_IGNORE algo instead of `insert` to ignore operation if value is already present in table